# Adding element padding through multiple data attribute values?

Tags: jquery, html

I created a code that works well: https://jsfiddle.net/f8vzkueh/

```
<div class="box" data-padding="20">Padding</div>
```

and:

```
$('*').each(function() {
  var p_all = $(this).data("padding");
  $(this).css('padding', p_all);
});
```

Now, my question is: Is it possible to add element padding through multiple data attribute values?

For example (top and bottom only):

```
<div class="box" data-padding="20 0 20 0">Padding</div>
```

...or (left and right only):

```
<div class="box" data-padding="0 20 0 20">Padding</div>
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: Well of course you can, but they need to have the measuring unit on them (px, in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS `padding` rule allows you to enter 1, 2, 3 or 4 values. If you use 1 value it's applied to all sides. If 2 values, then the first is used for top/bottom and the second left/right. If 3, the first is used for the top, the second for the right and left, the third for the bottom. If 4, then each side is specified individually going top, right, bottom, left.

With that in mind all you need to do is amend your `data` attribute to include units, eg. `20px 0`. You can also provide a function to the `css()` method to avoid the explicit `each()` loop:

```js
$('.box').css('padding', function() {
  return $(this).data('padding');
});
```

```css
.box { border: 1px solid #c00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-padding="20px">20 Padding</div>
<div class="box" data-padding="20px 0">20 0 Padding</div>
<div class="box" data-padding="20px 0 50px">20 0 50 Padding</div>
<div class="box" data-padding="20px 10px 5px 15px">20 10 5 15 Padding</div>
```

Note that I used a specific selector to retrieve the elements. Using the wildcard `*` selector can lead to performance issues, so I'd suggest you avoid it where possible.

Comment: Thank you, @Rory! This is a simple and awesome. :) I added both, padding and margin: https://jsfiddle.net/f8vzkueh/1/

Comment: Hi, @Rory! I have an additional question. What if selector is not / can not be assigned? Can it be used globally without a selector? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to `split()` your attribute value and *voilà* !

*PS : I also restricted the loop to elements that have the attribute `data-padding`.*

```js
$('[data-padding]').each(function() {
  var p_all = $(this).data("padding");
  var current_padding = p_all.split(' ');
  
  var finalPadding = '';
  for(var i = 0; i<current_padding.length;i++){
    finalPadding += current_padding[i] + 'px ';
  }
  $(this).css('padding', finalPadding);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-padding="20 0 20 0">Padding</div>
```